# Looping through the elements of a path variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to loop through a path list that I have gotten from an `echo $VARIABLE` command.

For example:

`echo $MANPATH` will return

`/usr/lib:/usr/sfw/lib:/usr/info`

So that is three different paths, each separated by a colon. I want to loop though each of those paths. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Thanks for all the replies so far, it looks like I actually don't need a loop after all. I just need a way to take out the colon so I can run one `ls` command on those three paths.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Bash's pattern substitution [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to populate your loop variable. For example:

```
MANPATH=/usr/lib:/usr/sfw/lib:/usr/info

# Replace colons with spaces to create list.
for path in ${MANPATH//:/ }; do
    echo "$path"
done
```

Note: Don't enclose the substitution expansion in quotes. You want the expanded values from MANPATH to be interpreted by the for-loop as separate words, rather than as a single string.

Comment: And what if they contain spaces?

Comment: To the best of my understanding, this does not work when any of the substrings contain spaces, which is exactly why the $PATH uses a non-space separator. @choroba's answer below is correct in this regard.

Comment: @intelfx: The question is tagged [tag:linux]. If you've got spaces in your *MANPATH* on Linux, then you're doing Linux wrong. Q.E.D.

Comment: @CodeGnome: The question is about colon-delimited lists in general, not necessarily `$MANPATH`. Therefore, your comment is non-sense, and your answer is still wrong as it breaks on valid input.

Comment: Parameter expansion to replace the colon with a space answers the bottom remark appropriately. The first part however, looping through a variable with a field separator is what `IFS` is for. Anything else is most likely broken code that will struggle with spaces, tabs, and newlines.

Comment: partially good arppoach - it saves from dealing with IFS - but it might fail when there are some spaces in the path string already.

Answer (score 66):

You can set the Internal Field Separator:

```
( IFS=:
  for p in $MANPATH; do
      echo "$p"
  done
)
```

I used a subshell so the change in IFS is not reflected in my current shell.

Comment: I believe this is the one that works even if $MANPATH contains whitespace.

Comment: Yes! This is the only answer that works consistently with paths containing whitespace (or whatever the IFS is on your system). Tested on Cygwin, Fedora, Ubuntu, and workedd for me on $PATH

Comment: Handles spaces well, but doesn't handle glob characters.

Comment: The comment by @codeforester about glob characters is correct.  The problem is easy to fix though: put `set -o noglob` before the `for` loop.

Comment: Not safe if the path contains a newline. See gniourf_gniourf's answer instead.

Comment: a sub shell will not allow you to return any result variables!

Answer (score 27):

The canonical way to do this, in Bash, is to use the `read` builtin appropriately:

```
IFS=: read -r -d '' -a path_array < <(printf '%s:\0' "$MANPATH")
```

This is the only robust solution: will do exactly what you want: split the string on the delimiter `:` and be safe with respect to spaces, newlines, and glob characters like `*`, `[ ]`, etc. (unlike the other answers: they are all broken).

After this command, you'll have an array `path_array`, and you can loop on it:

```
for p in "${path_array[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$p"
done
```

Comment: Why do you use `<(printf ...)` instead of just `<<<"$MANPATH"`?

Comment: Ah... you need this (including `-d ''`) to handle newlines in filenames correctly.
It's also important to point out for what the colon in `'%s:\0'` is: Without it, the script would fail for an empty/unset `$MANPATH`.

Comment: Instead of the `<(printf ...)` a usual `<(echo -n "$MANPATH:")` seems to work as well by the way.

Comment: @choroba, of course not. Seems to be a quite unusual path. But I got your point ;)

Comment: The first statement (`IFS=:...`) results in *Syntax error: redirection unexpected*

Answer (score 7):

In this way you can safely go through the `$PATH` with a single loop, while `$IFS` will remain the same inside or outside the loop.

```
while IFS=: read -d: -r path; do # `$IFS` is only set for the `read` command
    echo $path
done <<< "${PATH:+"${PATH}:"}"   # append an extra ':' if `$PATH` is set
```

You can check the value of `$IFS`,

```
IFS='xxxxxxxx'
while IFS=: read -d: -r path; do
    echo "${IFS}${path}"
done <<< "${PATH:+"${PATH}:"}"
```

and the output will be something like this.

```
xxxxxxxx/usr/local/bin
xxxxxxxx/usr/bin
xxxxxxxx/bin
```

Reference to [another question on StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18886).

Comment: Not all shells provide the `-d` option for `read`. Also, the way that `read` interacts with `IFS` is just that `echo a:b:c | while IFS=: read x yz; do echo "x=($x) yz=($yz)"; done` will print `x=(a) yz=(b:c)`. When you've got just a single variable after `read`, as you do in this answer, setting `IFS` does nothing. This contrasts the way that `for` interacts with `IFS`, as in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11655875/272427).

Comment: My system (macOS 12.5) has a `read` with the `-d` option.  I tried this solution and I found that using `IFS=:` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
for p in $(echo $MANPATH | tr ":" " ") ;do
    echo $p
done
```

Comment: -1 for the unquoted variable interpolations, the undesirable `echo` and the subprocess when the substitution can be performed by the shell.

Comment: It needs quotes, but it's also a lot more readable than the shell-built-in line noise.  Subshells are not the enemy.

Comment: This can't be fixed (just) by adding quotes, and it's got at least one other problem that @tripleee did not mention.  See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803).  However the current very low score seems harsh given that it's functionally not much worse than the accepted "solution".

Comment: A both much more succinct and more correct solution would be `tr '.' '\n' <<<"$MANPATH"` ...  though doing something more than just printing the values needs something more complex anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=:
arr=(${MANPATH})
for path in "${arr[@]}" ; do # <- quotes required
   echo $path
done
```

... it does take care of spaces :o) but also adds empty elements if you have something like:

```
:/usr/bin::/usr/lib:
```

... then index 0,2 will be empty (''), cannot say why index 4 isnt set at all

Comment: This does not handle glob characters.

Comment: Urk!  Needs to restore IFS

Answer (score 1):

This can also be solved with Python, on the command line:

```
python -c "import os,sys;[os.system(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]).format(p)) for p in os.getenv('PATH').split(':')]" echo {}
```

Or as an alias:

```
alias foreachpath="python -c \"import os,sys;[os.system(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]).format(p)) for p in os.getenv('PATH').split(':')]\""
```

With example usage:

```
foreachpath echo {}
```

The advantage to this approach is that `{}` will be replaced by each path in succession. This can be used to construct all sorts of commands, for instance to list the size of all files and directories in the directories in `$PATH`. including directories with spaces in the name:

```
foreachpath 'for e in "{}"/*; do du -h "$e"; done'
```

Here is an example that shortens the length of the `$PATH` variable by creating symlinks to every file and directory in the `$PATH` in `$HOME/.allbin`. This is not useful for everyday usage, but *may* be useful if you get the `too many arguments` error message in a `docker` container, because `bitbake` uses the full `$PATH` as part of the command line...

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/.allbin"
python -c "import os,sys;[os.system(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]).format(p)) for p in os.getenv('PATH').split(':')]" 'for e in "{}"/*; do ln -sf "$e" "$HOME/.allbin/$(basename $e)"; done'
export PATH="$HOME/.allbin"
```

This should also, in theory, speed up regular shell usage and shell scripts, since there are fewer paths to search for every command that is executed. It **is** pretty hacky, though, so I don't recommend that **anyone** shorten their `$PATH` this way.

The `foreachpath` alias might come in handy, though.

Answer (score 1):

Combining ideas from:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29949759 - [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31017384 - [Yi H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881930/yi-h)

code:

```
PATHVAR='foo:bar baz:spam:eggs:'  # demo path with space and empty
printf '%s:\0' "$PATHVAR" | while IFS=: read -d: -r p; do
    echo $p
done | cat -n
```

output:

```
1   foo
2   bar baz
3   spam
4   eggs
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash's for X in ${} notation to accomplish this:

```
for p in ${PATH//:/$'\n'} ; do
    echo $p;
done
```

Comment: This doesn't handle spaces.

Answer (score 0):

OP's update wants to `ls` the resulting folders, and has pointed out that `ls` only requires a space-separated list.

`ls $(echo $PATH | tr ':' ' ')` is nice and simple and should fit the bill nicely.